# How can I return the values from the interface methods into a JSON object?

Tags: c#, json, interface

I want to return a C# class as a JSON object:

This is my code of my switch:

```
 public IDatasource GetDataSource(DataSourceType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case DataSourceType.CONTROL:
                return new ControlDS();
            case DataSourceType.RISK:
                return new RiskDS();
            case DataSourceType.MOI:
                return new MoiDS();
            case DataSourceType.LOSSEVENTS:
                return new LossEventDS();
            case DataSourceType.KRI:
                return new KriDS();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
```

For each type it must return a whole class. Let's take for example type is `KRI` and it must return the class `KriDS` this is how it looks like:

```
 public class KriDS : IDatasource
    {
        public string Description()
        {
            var description = "This is a description";
            return description;
        }

        public string Name()
        {
            var kriname = "Test1";
            return kriname;
        }

        public int[] Values()
        {
            int[] values = new int[] { 1, 5, 7, 6, 7 };
            return values;
        }
    }
```

And in my controller I use the following method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public string GetDataSource(string id)
    {
       // var type = (DataSourceType)id;
        DataSourceType type;
        if(!Enum.TryParse(id, out type))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        var o = _dashboarBusiness.GetDataSource(type = DataSourceType.KRI);
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
    }
```

When I return the `var o` I want to return as this

```
{"description": "This is a description", "name": "Test1", "values": "[{1 5, 7, 6, 7}]"}
```

When I return it the object is null.

How can I return the values of the methods into a JSON object?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Kind regards

Comment: You need to use field/property instead of methods.

Comment: Yes, you can't serialize methods, replace them with properties or fields.

Comment: And don't serialize to JSON yourself. Let the framework do that. Just return the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of methods you need to create fields/properties. Methods can populate those. Try using this:

```
public class KriDS : IDatasource
{
    public string description = "This is a description";
    public string name = "Test1";
    public int[] values = new int[] { 1, 5, 7, 6, 7 };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must define properties or fields to serialize your object. For example :

```
public class KriDS : IDatasource
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] Values { get; set; }

    public KriDS()
    {
        Description = "This is a description";
        Name = "Test1";
        Values = new int[] { 1, 5, 7, 6, 7 };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you make your methods static you could assign cosibonding fields to them if you want to.

```
public class TestObj
{      
    public String someString = SomeString();        

    public static String SomeString()
    {
        return "a String";
    }
}
```

The json searialiser only Serialises fields