# How can I bind the results to the constructor properties in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I have build an interface with properties:

```
 public interface IDatasource
    {
        string Name { get; }
        string Description { get; }
        List<GraphPoint> Point { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I made a class that implements this interface:

```
public class RiskDS : IDatasource
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<GraphPoint> Point { get; set; }

    public RiskDS()
    {
        Name = "Risk overview";
        Description = "Blaat";
        Point = new List<GraphPoint> { new GraphPoint()
        {   Name = "Result of GetNetRisk",
            Description = "Result of GetNetRisk",
            Xname = "Result of GetNetRisk",
            Yname = "Result of GetNetRisk",
            Xaxis = new List<int> { 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 4, 1 }, //Result of GetNetRisk
            Yaxis = new List<int> { 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 4, 1 }  //Result of GetNetRisk
        }
        };
    }


    public static string GetNetRisks(long organizationId)
    {
        var _riskDashboardBusiness = new RiskDashboard();           
        var result = _riskDashboardBusiness.GetScoresOfLastTwoPeriods(organizationId, Data.Common.Enums.ORM.RiskScoringType.Net);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.None);
    }
}
```

So far so good but now I want to bind the results of `GetNetRisks` to the properties in the constructor. After that I want to give this object to the controller so I can bind it on the frontend with angularjs:

This is my `controller` function:

```
[HttpGet]
        public string GetDataSource(string id)
        {
           // var type = (DataSourceType)id;
            DataSourceType type;
            Enum.TryParse(id, out type);
            var o = _dashboarBusiness.GetDataSource(type = DataSourceType.CONTROL);
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
    }
```

In my previous question you can find more information about my factory pattern implementation:

[How can I return the values from the interface methods into a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182928/how-can-i-return-the-values-from-the-interface-methods-into-a-json-object)

How can I bind the results into the constructor so I can give it to the controller?

Kind regards

Comment: What is the result of `GetNetRisks`? Does it match the object you want to return?

Comment: Yes its like `{"name": "Tax", "description": "test1", "Xname": "xaxis", "Yname": "yaxis", "Xaxis": "[3, 4, 5]", "Yaxis": "[2, 6, 7]"}` this results I want to bind it to the constructors properties

Comment: Sounds like you need another class implementing your interface, then you can deserialize the result of ``GetNetRisks`` to it, and simply copy the properties into the properties of your constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about simple deserialization from Json?

```cs
public RiskDS()
{
    Name = "Risk overview";
    Description = "Blaat";
    var netRisks = GetNetRisks(/* organization id */);
    Point = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GraphPoint>>(netRisks);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I looking for but didn't knew the syntax.